# Enforce an Order to Rails Callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can one enforce an order of callbacks? For example, how do you ensure that `Step 1` happens before `Step 2`:

```
after_save do
  logger.info "Step 1"
end

after_save do
  logger.info "Step 2"
end
```

My actual example relates to using third party gems and ensuring that they have completed (they work on callbacks) before my own callbacks. I must use the same callback (i.e. cannot use a `before` and `after` combination).

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use class-level callbacks, they are called in the order they are defined.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_save :step1
  after_save :step2

private

  def step1
    # stuff
  end

  def step2
    # stuff
  end
end
```

For the third-party gem, it depends on how you interact with the gem, but odds are they will be called first because they were loaded first.

I would not recommend using the `def after_save` style at all, particularly when dealing with a third-party gem.

Comment: The `def after_save` was a typo (I've updated the example). The gem isn't being called first (it is very similar to `paperclip`, and I am defining the `has_attached_file` above my custom callback). Any other ideas on enforcing an order?

Comment: After forking the gem I was able to fix the ordering. You are correct in that the order of definition is all that matters! Thanks!