# are before_save callbacks executed in order declared rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Having trouble confirming this. Are 'before_save' callbacks executed in the order that they are written?

e.g.

```
before_save :first, :second

def first
  #some code
end

def second
  #some code
end
```

Will `first` always be called before `second`? Can someone please just give a yes or no answer?

I've read the rails documentation, specifically cancelling callbacks but it doesn't directly answer this question with a yes/no.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Yes the callbacks are executed in the order that they are defined.

```
   after_create :do_this, :and_then_this
```

Possible Duplicate of 
[Enforce an Order to Rails Callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392443/enforce-an-order-to-rails-callbacks)